# Firebase Google Analytics - Show number of events by parameter values filter

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I have an event `level_finish` with two parameters: `points` and `level_name`

In Firebase console (or Google Analytics) I want to see the amount of `level_finish` events, with query `level_name == "desert" AND points >= 10`.

Or, any other similar query.

I know there is BigQuery editor, but it is not free and unfriendly. Is there any way to perform such query right in Firebase or Google Analytics dashboards? Or any other free and friendly way?

Comment: Hi, did you end up finding how to do this ?

Comment: Unfortunately no, still waiting for answer.